# Snowflake unique split_to_table

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, etl, transformation

I have a table as follows in Snowflake:

[image]

What I am trying to do is split column B and C into new rows so each record is on its own. Like so:
[image]

I have tried using the below, and it is close to the solution unfortunately I am getting each record in **B** attached to each record in **C**. Whilst I want to keep them individual, so 2 = Tree, then 3 = Metal and so on.

This is my current approach and the result:

```
SELECT A, Y.VALUE, Z.VALUE
FROM TEST,
LATERAL split_to_table(B, ',')Y,
LATERAL split_to_table(C, ',')Z;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flatten them out in separate table expressions in a CTE and join them on the sequence and index:

```
create or replace transient table T1 (A string, B string, C string);
insert into T1 (A, B, C) values 
('Red', '2,3,4','Tree,Metal,House'),
('Green', '5,9,10','Building,Branch,Hose'),
('Blue','10,11,12,14','Roof,Tile,Van,Car')
;


with B as
(
select A, SEQ, INDEX, VALUE as B from T1, table(split_to_table(B, ','))
), C as
(
select SEQ, INDEX, VALUE as C from T1, table(split_to_table(C, ','))
)
select A, B, C from B left join C on B.SEQ = C.SEQ and B.INDEX = C.INDEX;
```

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Red | 2 | Tree |
| Red | 3 | Metal |
| Red | 4 | House |
| Green | 5 | Building |
| Green | 9 | Branch |
| Green | 10 | Hose |
| Blue | 10 | Roof |
| Blue | 11 | Tile |
| Blue | 12 | Van |
| Blue | 14 | Car |

Answer (score 0):

Assuming B and C have the same number of elements, you could just use the index from the first lateral join to get the corresponding elements in C

```
select a, y.value as b, split_part(c,',',y.index) as c
from t,
lateral split_to_table(b, ',') y
```